# Making trends in line graphs more or less prominent based on their occurence

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, tidyr, tidyverse

This is in relationship with this blog post by Simon - [Plotting individual observations and group means with ggplot2](https://www.r-bloggers.com/plotting-individual-observations-and-group-means-with-ggplot2/) and a previous question of mine where Mr Snake gave a nice solution.

I have a dataset of 600 individuals. For each individual I have a value for an indicator for 4 years - 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017. The value of the indicator takes a value 0-5 for 2014, and 1-4 for the rest of the years. In each year the value can either stay the same as previous year or increase but it cannot go down. I am trying to plot line graphs such that there is a separate line graph for each individual representing the trend of values of indicators through time, so the X-axis is time, and y-asis is indicator value. Below I am giving a minimum sample data needed to illustrate my problem of 17 rows (each row is for one individual and there are total 600 rows/individuals).

```
df <- data.frame(c(1:17), c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1), 
c(3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,2,1,1,1), c(3,3,3,3,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,2,1,1,3), c(3,4,3,3,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,3,4,2,1,1,3)) 
colnames(df) <- c("individual_id", paste("indicator_level_", 14:17, sep=""))
```

I am using the following code to achieve this -

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <-df %>%
gather(indicator_level_14, indicator_level_15, indicator_level_16, indicator_level_17, key="Level", value = "Level_value")

ggplot(df1, aes(x=Level, y=Level_value, color=as.factor(individual_id))) +
  geom_line(aes(group = individual_id)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(color = "Sample") + theme(legend.position="none")
```

The trouble I am having is, that since my levels are very discrete and a lot of individuals' level trajectories across time is same, several line graphs are overlapping make it difficult for me to see which are the more prominent trajectories. This gets intensified when I plot the line graphs for all 600 individuals. Is there a way that the thickness of each line graph be proportional to the count of overlapping trajectories?

Comment: Hi and thanks for posting. There are few problems reproducing your code. Eg, variable names in `gather` and `ggplot` don't match those in `d`. Please edit appropriately. Also, it would be good to see the output you get to help explain (or even better, see) the output you desire.

Comment: Thanks Simon and sorry about var name inconsistencies. I have corrected those - see my edit above. The output I get is individual trend lines over time. As you re-produce the graph, you will notice that while individuals are 17, lines are fewer because several of them are super-imposes. I wanted to identify the more prominent trend lines over less prominent ones - is there a way that can be done visually? I used the following packages - 
ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr, magrittr

Comment: what do you mean by prominent? is it a sum of level_value?

Comment: I meant more frequent (or repeated) trends. E.g. if two individuals each had values let's say 0, 3, 3, 4 for years 2014, 15, 16 and 17 respectively and only one individual had a trend 0, 1, 2, 2, then I wanted the trend line that's getting repeated to be highlighted in some way

Comment: A quick fix is to use `alpha = 0.25` (or similar) on your lines. That way four lines would add up to one solid line, but one line would be 75% transparent.

Comment: Use of `alpha` also goes nicely with `size`. Something like `geom_line(aes(group = individual_id), alpha = .1, size = 3)`. Aside, not a thought-out idea, but might be worth looking into directed graphs to find weights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Level, Level_value) %>%               # Find each unique leg
  mutate(count = length(individual_id)) %>%      # Count how many are on each leg
  ggplot(aes(Level, Level_value, group = individual_id, size = count)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.5,3))
```

[image]

---

```
df1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(Level, Level_value, group = individual_id)) + 
  geom_line(alpha = 0.25, size = 2)
```

[image]

---

```
 df %>%
  group_by(indicator_level_14,               # Find each unique full path
           indicator_level_15, 
           indicator_level_16, 
           indicator_level_17) %>% 
  mutate(count = length(individual_id)) %>%  # Count indivs on each path
  gather(Level, Level_value, -individual_id, -count) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Level, Level_value, group = individual_id, size = count)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.5,3))
```

Comment: For some reason I can't post a picture of the last code snippet, but you can run it and see what the output is like.

Comment: Brian, love the counting of all unique trends solution - thank you! On running the last code I get this error - Error in resolve_vars(new_groups, tbl_vars(.data)) : 
  unknown variable to group by : indicator_level_14. Do you know why that could be?

Comment: Did you possibly change the data? That error would indicate that `indicator_level_14`  isn't in `df`.

Comment: Okay I will check! Thanks again